# Vuex state not consisting after reload

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I use a sortable list connected to a vuex store and get it like:

```
        let nested = computed({
            get: () => {
                return store.getters.getItems;
            }
        });
```

When now changing the order of the elements the store reactively should adapt. When doing a `console.log` inside the store like:

```
        console.log(state.line_items_attributes.nested_form);
        var temp = cloneDeep(data.nested_form);
        state.line_items_attributes.nested_form = temp;
        console.log(state.line_items_attributes.nested_form);
```

The values before and after the assignment are exactly the same.

So it shouldn't matter if I use that mutation or not. But when removing it, and then refreshing the page the store is back to what it was before rearranging the list elements.

Comment: If `CHECK_ORDER` is the only mutation you use in your action, what do you expect when you remove it?

Comment: @StevenSiebert I expect the state (the list) to be updated without that mutation, cause of the reactivity it should have. Cause that mutation doesn't do anything despite logging it to the console.

Comment: Thats not how you should use `vuex`. You need to pass the new state with a mutation, else it wouldn´t be persisted.

Comment: @StevenSiebert Okay, then I'll do it like that. thanks.
Is it just okay as I already do it in the question? Or should I safe the new state in an separate object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As currently written, you don´t mutate your state in `vuex`, you mutate it outside of your store, which is the wrong way to do it. In this case, reactivity works from store to component, not the other way round.

In your case, to update your state with the new order, you simply do it like you maybe already doing in other mutations:

```
CHECK_ORDER: (state, data) => {
   state.line_items_attributes = data;
   console.log(state.line_items_attributes);
}
```

Else you should also receive the following error while mutating outside of a mutation:

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

---

**Quick tip: Use a copy of your state**

If you need to manipulate something outside of your store first and want to mutate the state later, you could get it like this:

```
this.localItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(store.getters.getItems))
```

In this case `localItems` wont have a reference to your state in the store. As meantioned, [vue.draggable.next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) provides a couple of events you could use to dispatch the sorted object `localItems` to the store while doing so.

You can see those events in [Events | vue.draggable.next](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next#events)

Small example:

```
// HTML
<draggable :list="list" @end="onEnd">

// Function 
onEnd() {
   this.$store.dispatch('myAction', this.localItems)
}

// vuex Action
myAction({commit}, newItems) {
   commit('UPDATE_MY_ITEMS', newItems);
}

// vuex Mutation
UPDATE_MY_ITEMS(state,payload) {
   state.items = payload;
}
```

Comment: Tho I am using SortableJS/vue.draggable.next to do the rearragning of the elements. That makes it slightly more difficult.

Comment: @TKsomewhat According to the docs on [git](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next) it is possible to call a function with `:move="checkMove"`. You could add a `dispatch` to that.

Comment: So how would I bind the list to an object without mutating it directly outside the store then? You mentioned currently I'm doing this.

Comment: I assumed you already do this in other modules of your store, if you had them. I´ll try to edit my answer with a quick tip.

Comment: All right, thanks! The copy of the state was exactly what I needed then.
But wouln't it make the use of the computed property needless?